# How to get root cause of a FacesException?

Tags: java, exception, jsf-2

We use JSF2 `ExceptionHandler` to catch the exceptions. All the runtime exceptions are caught in the exception handler with exact stack trace.

But the object is coming as `FacesException`. Is there any way to get the root cause of the exception, say `NullPointerException`, from the `FacesException` object?

Comment: For future reference: `javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.getRootCause(Throwable)`, despite its name, [does not traverse all the way back to the real root cause](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandlerWrapper.html#getRootCause(java.lang.Throwable)): *"Unwrap the argument t until the unwrapping encounters an Object whose getClass() is not equal to FacesException.class or javax.el.ELException.class. If there is no root cause, null is returned."*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use the [`getCause()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/FacesException.html#getCause%28%29) method which is inherited from [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) (and thus available on every exception and error):

```
Throwable cause = facesException.getCause();
// ...
```

If you want to specifically check for `NullPointerException` (the why is beyond me as that's usually a developer error, not an user error, but that aside), then you could do an `instanceof` check:

```
if (cause instanceof NullPointerException) {
    // The cause is a NullPointerException.
}
```

Comment: if (cause instanceof NullPointerException) {
 doesn't work , it is still FacesException...only the detailMessage of the Throwable has got the "NullPointerException" info . NullPointerException object is not accessible.

Comment: Apparently it's wrapped in another `FacesException` somehow. Just do a `if (cause instanceof FacesException) { Throwable nestedCause = cause.getCause(); if (nestedCause instanceof NullPointerException) ... }` etc (you can do it better in a `for` loop btw).